# JDBC Connector Issues

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having trouble using the JDBC Connector.  I got it to work in Eclipse but it doesn't seem to work from command line.  I re-named the connector "driver.jar" and put it into a /lib directory in the folder of my Main class.  I even set the class path to the /lib/driver.jar but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  Can someone please advise me on how to setup the JDBC so that I can connect to a MySQL database.  This is really frustrating.

Sample Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Database credentials
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
        String db = "db";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        // Connect to database
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println("HELLO");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","");
            System.out.println("Success");
            } catch(Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please post what you use on the command line to compile/run the program as well as the error message?

Comment: javac Main.java
java Main

It's not throwing me any error message.  It's just not executing the code entirely.  For example, it doesn't print "HELLO".

Comment: I had it print the eMessage and it says " com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: Try `>java -cp .;c:\folder\driver.jar Main`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I hope, it is not able to locate driver library file for MYSQL.

Try this

Copy the driver.jar in JRE/lib/ext

Ex. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0\lib\ext

Comment: Great!  Thanks for your help.  I'm running MAC OSX so I put it into the /Library/Java/Extensions/ and it seems to work fine now!!

Comment: Don't put libraries in \lib\ext it is a great way to screw up programs which depends on specific versions of a library.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Mark Rotteveel where put the jar file into lib\ext\ is not an elegant solution.

You may try what @AVD suggest, but use ":" as seperator since you run your program on Mac OSX.

Example (assuming your Main.class and lib/ are in same folder):

```
>java -cp .:./lib/driver.jar Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, to get the connection, please replace the Username and Password with yours in the getConnection() method. Try to work on this, if it works for you then please see whats the probs with your code.

```
public class DBDiary {

    Connection conn;


    public DBDiary(){

        this.getConn();

    }

    public Connection getConn(){

        try {
            conn = getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
        }
           return conn;
    }


    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        String drivers = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";

        System.setProperty(drivers,"");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a desktop application then you need to put it in build Path of project in eclipse

and if you are developing web application like web service or something else then you need to add this file into this file project_folder\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib  it will work .
and then you can communicate to mysql as @Arun P Johny said.
Still have any problem then write me.